# Transform &amp; in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm relatively new to XSLT.  I've come across an issue that I don't know how to get around.  I have an pretty large XML document that I am trying to transform to into another smaller, refined XML document.

The large XML document has this style:

```
 <Property>
  <name>Document name</name>
  <value>SomeValue</value>   
 </Property>
...
 <Property>
  <name>Document Title</name>
  <value>Me %amp; you</value>   
 </Property>
```

How do you transform the value in between the value elements and keep the "&amp"; intact.  Apparently transforming this XML is causing errors due to that ampersand escape in the text.

Note: This large XML is generated by a application that pulls data from a server. So I'm kinda of stuck dealing with the escape ampersand :(

Comment: Your question is not clear. Whenever you serialize your output with XML (or HTML) method, `&` character will be escape as `&amp;` entity reference as XML specs demand. Only when you serialize output with `text` method, escape is not performed.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple example of a transformation with the required property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a simple (and very fundamental) example, using the identity rule:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML file**:

```
<t>
 <Property>
  <name>Document name</name>
  <value>SomeValue</value>
 </Property>
...
 <Property>
  <name>Document Title</name>
  <value>Me &amp; you</value>
 </Property>
</t>
```

**it is transformed into itself (identity):**

```
<t>
   <Property>
      <name>Document name</name>
      <value>SomeValue</value>
   </Property>
...
 <Property>
      <name>Document Title</name>
      <value>Me &amp; you</value>
   </Property>
</t>
```

and the character `&amp;` is preserved.

Comment: +1 Thanks Dimitre! I will check this one once I do some test runs!